# Connect to Postgresql server on AWS RDS from PGADMIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I am trying to reach my database server from pgadmin but I keep getting this error

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not translate host name "dbname.xxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Unknown host
```

I followed these exact instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html
I could not find any solution to this specific problem

Comment: Getting the same kind of error when trying to connect from psql 
```psql: erreur : n'a pas pu se connecter au serveur : n'a pas pu traduire le nom d'hôte «dbname.xxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com » en adresse : Unknown host ```

Comment: it is a dns issue. Is this a new server? can you try to ping it first?

Comment: Yeah I tried to ping, didn't work. But I created the server yesterday. Can I get the ip address and connect with it ?

Comment: I don't recommend using ip address as that could change by AWS. Can you set your DNS Server to 8.8.8.8 and try to ping again

Comment: Thanks this DNS works, now I have another problem but not related to this topic

Comment: I will post this as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a DNS issue.
Please try using a Google's dns server 8.8.8.8 and if this resolves to a working host.

Comment: could be a dumb question, where in pgadmin4 in connection of db do we have dns option. something which it does not interfere with existing system and tables